# Getting started, how do I buy bitcoin

Tags: block, mining-profitability

I live in Nigeria,probably a third world market. This would be the first in this region. Would like to strongly promote this exchange Inot these parts of Africa. Please help.

Comment: It's really far-fetched, but have you tried putting something along the lines of "buy Bitcoin Nigeria" into a search engine? Much to my surprise, it comes up with sites like [Buy Bitcoin in Nigeria](https://www.buybitcoinworldwide.com/en/ng/), [Can I buy Bitcoin using Nigerian Naira?](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-buy-Bitcoin-using-Nigerian-Naira), [ICE3x Launches Nigeria's First Bitcoin Exchange](http://www.coindesk.com/ice3x-launches-nigerias-first-bitcoin-exchange/). Perhaps you should look at a few of them and then tell us more specifically what you need help with. ;)

Comment: I'm confused. This post doesn't contain a single coherent sentence. It shows no previous research, the asker didn't even do a websearch. The question is unclear and unfocused. The tags are completely unrelated. – How is this getting three upvotes? Why do you think this question "shows research effort, is useful and clear"? If you understand what the asker wants, please edit the question, or close it as a duplicate of one of the hundreds other "how do I buy Bitcoin?" questions.